# Android Studio Gradle Build Error Type Code 82

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, runtime-error

I am fairly new to Kotlin and Android Studio. When I tried to add a dependency to my Android application (the dependency is json-simple) it throwed me an error with the cause as `Invalid type code: 82`. Gradle had synced correctly without any warnings and errors, but it throws me this error when I try to run my code. Can anyone please tell me how to remedy this issue? The stacktrace is :-

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project D:\PathToProj

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :app:compileDebugSources
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class org.hamcrest.BaseDescription found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.Description found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.Factory found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.Matcher found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.StringDescription found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.AllOf found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.AnyOf found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.DescribedAs found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.Is found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsAnything found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsInstanceOf found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsNot found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsNull found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsSame found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.internal.ArrayIterator found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.internal.SelfDescribingValue found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  Duplicate class org.hamcrest.internal.SelfDescribingValueIterator found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
  
  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.6.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 18s
14 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 10 up-to-date
```

My build.gradle is as follows:-

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.techx.voiceassist"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    sourceCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

I have tried all other solutions describing this particular issue. None of them worked (including executing the `clean` task and running again). I also tried using the `lintFix` task (though I don't know what that is) to fix the issue but did'nt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue is describing a dependency conflict - basically the libraries you're using are bringing in two different copies of `hamcrest-core`, and Gradle doesn't know which one to use.

Googling around it looks like it *is* `json-simple` that's pulling in that dependency, and also `junit`. I don't know a lot about this, but one solution is to add

```
android {
    ....
    configurations { compile.exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"}
    ....
}
```

(so add that configurations block in your android section somewhere).

Honestly I'm not totally sure about all this - `json-simple` has a dependency on `JUnit 4.10`, and `JUnit 4.11` added new Hamcrest matchers - maybe Gradle can't be sure that `json-simple` will work with the newer library. Excluding JUnit with that `compile` exclusion might make Gradle ignore it during non-test builds, I'm not sure if it will affect testing though. I'm just giving you stuff to think about if this fix doesn't work and you run into issues!

Comment: ok then I'll maybe even try switching my code over to Jackson or Gson if possible. Thanks! @cactustictacs

Comment: hey @cactustictacs it is said the JSON Simple doesnt have any dependencies

Comment: It has a JUnit 4.10 dependency, look: https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/pom.xml